# Android scrollview shrinks imageview

Tags: android, imageview, scrollview

This is my **layout xml** with a `Relativelayout` in a `Scrollview`:-

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/separator1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/separator1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="Merry Xmas"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/separator2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/separator2"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/separator3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/image1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/separator3"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="Happy New Year"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Here are my problems:-

- If I remove the `ScrollView` tags, the `ImagView` stretches and **fills** up the width, which is what I want.
- If I add the `ScrollView` tags, it shrinks the `ImagView` for some reason.

Any **idea** how I can apply the `ScrollView` and have the `ImageView` fill up the width?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the RealtiveLayout to fill parent? Also I have noticed that sometimes a RelativeLayout shrinks imageViews. Perhaps you could try using a LinearLayout instead.

Comment: Tried everything you suggested with the same results.

Comment: If you only add your ImageView into the ScrollView will it shrink it? If yes then the ScrollView may have default padding, which you can set on zero. Also with the ImageView android:scaleType="fitCenter" you may try different setting. I don't have your images to experiment myself...

Comment: Yes it shrinks the image if just the imageview in the scrollview. I got rid of the android:scaleType, tried to set android:padding="0dp" for both the scrollview and imageview, still nada.

Comment: fillViewPort=true gives me the correct size but then the scrolling becomes disabled.

Comment: Are you programmaticaly loading the image in the image view? Because your layout works fine if the ImageView preloads an image: android:src="@drawable/my_image"

Comment: Yeah I'm downloading an image and adding it to the imageView.

Comment: I think that an empty image view is initially formated smaller and when you load the image it just fills the smaller ImageView frame. You can set a default image of the right size in the ImageView like a transparent png. Or maybe there is a better solution to force the ImageView to resize itself...

Comment: Forcing a size works, problem is with different phone sizes it's hard to cater for them, oh well, guess I will try a design workaround. Thanks anyway.